# HTML Selector using python’s bs4

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

I’m fairly new at this, and I’m trying to work through Automate the Boring stuff and make some of my own programs along the way. I’m trying to use beautiful soup’s ‘select’ method to pull the value ‘33’ out of this code

```
<span class="wu-value wu-value-to" _ngcontent-c19="">33</span>
```

I know that the span element is inside a div and i’ve tried a few selectors including:

```
high_temp = w_u_soup.select('div > span .wu-value wu-value-to')
```

But I haven’t been able to get 33 out. Any help would be appreciated. I’ve tried to look up what _ngcontent-c19 is, but I’m having trouble understanding what i’ve found thus far (I’m trying to learn python and it seems I’ll be learning a bit of HTML as a consequence)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a couple of different issues here.

First, your selector is wrong -- the selector you have is trying to select an element called `wu-value-to` (which isn't a valid HTML element) inside something with class `wu-value` inside a `span` which is a direct descendent of a `div`. To select an element *with* particular classes you need no space between the element name and the class descriptors.

So your selector should probably be `div > span.wu-value.wu-value-to`. If your entire HTML is the part you showed, just 'span' would be enough, but I'm guessing you are being specific by specifying the parent and those classes for a reason.

Second, you are selecting the element, not its text content. You need `your_node.text` to get the text content.

Putting it together, you should be able to get what you want with this:

```
w_u_soup.select('div > span.wu-value.wu-value-to').text
```

Comment: spot on. that worked. follow up question: I figured that the problem with the selector had to do with the space between wu-value and wu-value-to in the HTML. I get that it needs to be read as one class, but why can you replace that space with a '.'?

Comment: HTML and its `class` attribute, and CSS selectors (which is what you put in CSS and also in BS4's `select` method) are just different beasts. In HTML, you specify multiple classes in a `class` attribute by space-separating them. In CSS selectors, `.name` means a thing with the class `name` (potentially among other classes). `.name1.name2` would select an element with both, and they could be in either order there (and in the HTML). So I think you may have misunderstood -- you could leave off either or both of the classes in your selector, as long as it's still unique among your input data.